# How does PHP assess MIMEtypes of uploaded files?

Tags: php, mime-types

Is it simply based on the file extension?

Do we get PHP's full analysis of the file type with the command `$_FILES["fileName"]["type"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the manual](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> `$_FILES['userfile']['type']`
>
> The mime type of the file, if the browser
>   provided this information. An example would be *"image/gif"*. This mime
>   type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take
>   its value for granted.

In other words, it's supplied by the browser and can't be trusted.

Comment: OK, but how does the browser get this info?  Does it just do a lookup on the file extension?

Comment: Probably - it doesn't matter though, you can't trust it to be correct.  A user, a piece of malware or any intervening software can modify it.

Comment: Depending on browser implementation, it can be either an os service or a browser maintained extension-mime type map. In either case, it should not be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP documentation states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) that:

> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information.
>   An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked
>   on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.